# Navigation drawer in androidx

Tags: android

I m new in android ,i had search many example which is related from navigation drawer and I also apply to our project but the last things that
In my project Humberger icon and navigation view(slide) are not work properly and humberger icon doesn't show .

I apply onCreatePost()

And many method apply such as configuration and other but there is not a solution.so how can I fix this problem.. in my system install Androidx

Comment: Dear @pushpenndra sharma show us what you tried before

Comment: Welcome to SO, please leave some references, sample code snippets or screenshots. So that we can able to understand your actual problem and help you to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I fixed it by adding the navigation graph into the Hosted Fragment, I'll post the layout code from the main view.

**main.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:openDrawer="start">

<!-- This layout contains the Action App Bar see the app_bar_main.xml code-->
        <include
            layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<!-- This is the Navigation drawer widget, Which opens when you click on the hamburger icon -->
<!-- For that you could add header view -->
<!-- Can add menu or custom view for navigation tabs -->
        <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main">
            <include layout="@layout/nav_body_main"/>
        </com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>

    </androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**app_bar_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/root_landing"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".ui.landing.main.MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**content_main**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation"/>
<!--  This navigation graph will sort the issue -->
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And find the Activity Code.

```
// Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
// menu should be considered as top level destinations.

 mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
          R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow,
           R.id.nav_tools, R.id.nav_share, R.id.nav_send)
           .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
           .build();

    navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController)
```

**Easiest Way**

The easiest way is to generate the code through the Android Studio since you are new.

RightClick on the Package folder -> New -> Activity -> Gallery

from that select Navigation Drawer Activity

Cheers!